# how to Merge Cells in datagridview VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I can merge the cells through cellpainting but it seems I dont know much on how to use it properly

using for loop I based my next row from the previous row and make the text empty but every time i have the cell empty in the first place, it goes merging with the cells above it.
I hope I explained it clearly though.. XD

Here is my Code

```
        Dim prev As String = dt.Rows(0)(0).ToString() '\\merge with column 0
        Dim prev1 As String = dt.Rows(0)(1).ToString() '\\merge with column 1
        For i = 1 To dt.Rows.Count - 1

            If dt.Rows(i)(0).ToString() = prev Then '\
                dt.Rows(i)(0) = ""                 '\
            Else
                prev = dt.Rows(i)(0).ToString()     '\ column 0 (blank the next row if the same with previous)
            End If                                  '\


            If dt.Rows(i)(1).ToString() = prev1 Then
                dt.Rows(i)(1) = ""                  '\ column 1 (blank the next row if the same with previous)
            Else
                prev1 = dt.Rows(i)(1).ToString()
            End If
        Next
```

Private Sub DGV1_CellPainting(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs) Handles DGV1.CellPainting

```
    If e.RowIndex > 0 Then
        If e.RowIndex < DGV1.Rows.Count - 2 Then
            For col = 0 To DGV1.ColumnCount - 1
                If DGV1.Rows(e.RowIndex + 1).Cells(col).Value.ToString() = "" Then
                    If (e.ColumnIndex = col) Then
                        e.AdvancedBorderStyle.Bottom = DataGridViewAdvancedCellBorderStyle.None

                    End If
                    'Else
                    '    e.AdvancedBorderStyle.Bottom = DataGridViewAdvancedCellBorderStyle.Single


                End If


                If DGV1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(col).Value.ToString() = "" Then
                    If (e.ColumnIndex = col) Then
                        e.AdvancedBorderStyle.Top = DataGridViewAdvancedCellBorderStyle.None
                    End If

                 End If
            Next
        End If
    End If

    If e.RowIndex = 0 Then
        For col = 0 To DGV1.ColumnCount - 1
            If DGV1.Rows(e.RowIndex + 1).Cells(col).Value.ToString() = "" Then
                If (e.ColumnIndex = col) Then
                    e.AdvancedBorderStyle.Bottom = DataGridViewAdvancedCellBorderStyle.None
                End If
            End If

        Next
    End If





End Sub
```

Note* please disregard the column header

my Output is always like this one
http://tinypic.com/r/2wqcokj/8

it should be like this one
http://tinypic.com/r/11gstg1/8